# How do I make css code run for a certain amount of time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to fix a double submit form problem. My solution was to load css code onClick to add a grey overlay and an animated loading icon in the center of the screen.

My question is, how would I add a setTimeout for the overlay and the icon? I only want the css code to run for approximately 6 seconds then for the users to regain access to the form.

```css
#cover-spin {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  z-index: 9999;
  display: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#cover-spin::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 48%;
  top: 40%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spin .8s linear infinite;
  animation: spin .8s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="cover-spin"></div>
  <button onclick="$('#cover-spin').show(0)">Submit</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem - why *6 seconds* exactly?  Why not 5.5s or 6.1s?  Better to remove the overlay when you get the result back from the server (ajax `.done()`) - if doing a form post, then no need to remove at all as the whole page will be updated.

Comment: I think you are going about it the wrong way, you dont want to have a timer to remove the css, what if the server takes longer to respond? best thing would be to add a class to you element to signify the submit has happened and remove it on server response rather then a set time. if this is a security concern then def dont use css to stop people re-submitting

Comment: the one problem is that the form validates on the server with php. it submits on avg 2 seconds so i think 6+ seconds should be good. no security concerns here though, im brand new to programming and just seeing how everything works lol

Comment: To address the real problem: how are you sending the data to the server?  `form` submit/post or `$.ajax` / `$.post` ?

Comment: its with $,post. the code you're seeing above is just a test file to see if i could get it working

Comment: Ok, use `$.post(url, data).done(function(result) { $("#cover-spin").hide(); })`

Comment: sweet, even better. didnt realize that was possible. thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the explicit question

> how would I add a setTimeout for the overlay and the icon

use `setTimeout` to run the opposite of what you do to show the overlay after a specific interval (in milliseconds):

```
$('#cover-spin').show();
setTimeout(function() { $('#cover-spin').hide(); }, 6000);
```

---

Updating your existing button `onclick` to:

```
<button onclick="$('#cover-spin').show();setTimeout(function() { $('#cover-spin').hide(); }, 6000);">Submit</button>
```

---

To answer the *implied* question:

> how do I hide a progress overlay when the submit has completed

`$.post` provides a callback function, but also returns a promise.  No need to worry about promises too much, just that it has a `.done` method which you can utilise:

```
$.post(url, data)
    .done(function(result) { 
        $("#cover-spin").hide(); 
    });
```

Comment: awesome thanks man, much appreciated. I'll accept your answer in 5mins when stackoverflow allows me :)

Answer (score 2):

So, There is something called `animation-duration`

So simply type this inside your CSS where you are calling the animation:

```
animation-duration: 6s;
```

Comment: cool, looks like there are many ways to do this then, thanks :D